# Minimize the variance of distances between 2 points for planar region of given area

Tags: general-topology, probability-distributions, topological-groups, geometric-probability

Given a region $S$ in the Euclidean plane, let $X$ and $Y$ be random points in $S$, independent and uniformly distributed.

If the area of $S$ is given (let's say it is 1), what is the shape of $S$ that minimizes the variance of distances,
$$
\operatorname{Var}(d(X,Y)),
$$
where $d$ is the Euclidean distance?

My guts says is a ball (in 2D). But I don't know how to prove it.

A more simple question is what shape will minimize the expectation of $d(X,Y)$. This time again I think its a ball, but I have some more sense.

Not a proof, but a direction, is that in any shape that is not a ball, there is a point that we can get closer to the center of mass of the group - hence decreasing the average distance from the rest of the points.

Comment: In a set There is no meaning to have the the same element more than once. You need to group points that sum to a volume of $S$. That of course cannot be done with a single point if $S>0$

Comment: I don't think I understand the question. Is $S$ a finite set containing $n$ points? Are there any other constraints on $S$? If you put all the points arbitrarily close to a single point (say, the origin), then you can make all distances $d(x,y)$ (and also their variance) arbitrarily small.

Comment: $S$ is not finite. $n$ is the area (or in higher dimensions - the volume) of the group $S$. So if let's say $n=1$, than a legal shape can be $S={(x,y) | 0<x<1 and 0<y<=1}$

Comment: Oh I see. So $S$ is actually a 2D region of given area. (We could simply take the area to be 1 then, all other areas you get by scaling.) Also I believe you are not referring to "groups" in the algebraic sense, so better just call them *regions* in plane.

Comment: Indeed you can scale it as you wish, so in some intuitive way, the "shape" is what important here. I am not so familiar with the phrases.. You are welcome to edit my question with better notation if you think it might be clearer :)

Comment: It may be clearer now.

Comment: The only "trivial" fact here is that the shape minimizing the average squared distance between the points is, indeed, the ball (in any dimension), but you, probably, know that much yourself...

Comment: Hi @fedja, I agree but I don't see it is that trivial.. Still couldn't find a valid proof for that.